# Wordpress navigation list does not show

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to display the wordpress navigation list on the ul but it does not show, if I write another words in the list item it shows, I could not identify the problem!!!

here is my code:
HTML

```
  <div class="menu-toggle">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
  <nav class="toggle-navg">
    <ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
        <li> <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'extra-menu', 'container_class' => 'my_extra_menu_class' ) ); ?></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.menu-toggle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index:99;
}
.menu-toggle.on .one {
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(7px, 7px);
}
.menu-toggle.on .two {
  opacity: 0;
}
.menu-toggle.on .three {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(8px, -10px);
}

.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: white;
  margin: 6px auto;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.toggle-navg ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 4em auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.toggle-navg ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.toggle-navg ul a {
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.toggle-navg  ul a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.menu-section.on {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.7;
}



.menu-toggle {
  left: 85%;
  }
```

Comment: Show us also the *rendered HTML*.  It's possible your menu is *empty*, in which case there would be nothing to show, and the solution is to ensure your menu is built, and that your `theme_location` matches.

Comment: you can inspect element, HTML is came or not

Answer (score 0):

The ul class : `.toggle-navg ul.hidden` hide your menu, try to remove this class:

```
.toggle-navg ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, still not working. this class hide the menu until I click the button

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add a sub menu? By that I mean a menu inside the li element?

This code:

```
<ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
    <li> <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'extra-menu', 'container_class' => 'my_extra_menu_class' ) ); ?></li>
</ul>
```

Would give you something like:

```
<ul role="navigation" class="hidden">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So is is possible that the child menu is being hidden?

Try running the wp_nav_menu outside of the menu to see if your menu appears - or use Inspect Element / Dev Tools / View Source to check that HTML is actually being output by your wp_nav_menu arguements.

You are also missing the "menu" arguement for wp_nav_menu().

Try this to output your menu as a standalone instead of the above (assuming your menu name is "extra-menu", if not - adjust to suit) :

```
 wp_nav_menu( array(
        'menu' => 'extra-menu',
        'theme_location'    => 'extra-menu',
        'menu_class' => 'hidden'
    );
```